# Using Workbook Variable in Workbooks(variablename).close Statement`

Tags: vba, excel

The filename changes so I use the wildcard * to refer to it in the Workbooks.Open statement

Last Line of code throws type mismatch error, how can I change the syntax to repair the code?

```
 Dim JohnnyFootball As Workbook
 Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "T:\ConA\RIP\Extracts\Reference" & "*.xlsx"     
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Set JohnnyFootball = ActiveWorkbook
   'Other [redacted] code here runs fine
   'Code below throws type mismatch error
  Workbooks(JohnnyFootball).Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last line should look like this:

```
JohnnyFootball.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

`JohnnyFootball` is `Workbook` variable. To get an element from `Workbooks` collection you have to pass it's name or index.

Comment: Take a  close look at his explanation for those of you who struggle with Syntax- this clarified a lot for me.